# The 'case' shouldn't complete normally

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error in this code and can't figure it out since it appears that it should work. The error is: The 'case' shouldn't complete normally. The error happens on the second case statement case PurchaseStatus.purchased. Dart should allow multiple case statements in this manner but not working.

```
      switch (purchaseDetails.status) {
        case PurchaseStatus.pending:
          _adRemoval = const AdRemovalPurchase.pending();
          notifyListeners();
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.restored:
        case PurchaseStatus.purchased:
          bool valid = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
          if (valid) {
            _adRemoval = const AdRemovalPurchase.active();
            if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
              showSnackBar('Thank you for your support!');
            }
            notifyListeners();
          } else {
            _log.severe('Purchase verification failed: $purchaseDetails');
            _adRemoval = AdRemovalPurchase.error(
                StateError('Purchase could not be verified'));
            notifyListeners();
          }
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.error:
          _log.severe('Error with purchase: ${purchaseDetails.error}');
          _adRemoval = AdRemovalPurchase.error(purchaseDetails.error!);
          notifyListeners();
        case PurchaseStatus.canceled:
          _adRemoval = const AdRemovalPurchase.notStarted();
          notifyListeners();
      }
```

Comment: You are missing a `break` in the he third case ...

Comment: @derpirscher I must be blind... the editor is showing the error on the second case statement... not the third case! Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Dart 2?  In Dart 3, [`case` clauses in Dart do not require `break` statements to prevent fall-through](https://dart.dev/language/branches#switch-statements).

Comment: It looks like an issue with the analyzer reporting the error on the wrong line.

Comment: @jamesdlin I did in fact copy code from a Dart 3 project to a Dart 2 project. This appears to be the root of the problem. Thanks!